# How to change the current day's hours and minutes in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate

If I create a `Date()` to get the current date and time, I want to create a new date from that but with different hour, minute, and zero seconds, what's the easiest way to do it using Swift? I've been finding so many examples with 'getting' but not 'setting'.

Comment: Had you try it with `NSDateFormatter`? and use `dateFromString` from it

Comment: I think this answer is better than converting to string and back again. That's why I asked "easiest way" in my question. I know there are a few ways to do this but I think using the components is best.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Be aware that for locales that uses Daylight Saving Times, on clock change days, some hours may not exist or they may occur twice. Both solutions below return a `Date?` and use force-unwrapping. You should handle possible `nil` in your app.

### Swift 3+ and iOS 8 / OS X 10.9 or later

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 9, minute: 30, second: 0, of: Date())!
```

### Swift 2

Use `NSDateComponents` / `DateComponents`:

```
let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let now = NSDate()
let components = gregorian.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: now)

// Change the time to 9:30:00 in your locale
components.hour = 9
components.minute = 30
components.second = 0

let date = gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)!
```

Note that if you call `print(date)`, the printed time is in UTC. It's the same moment in time, just expressed in a different timezone from yours. Use a `NSDateFormatter` to convert it to your local time.

Comment: How about Swift 4?

Comment: @AhmetAkkök Swift 3 example works in Swift 4 as well

Comment: how to change he am and pm

Comment: @A.s.ALI you just add 12 hours to it: `let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(hour:12), to: Date())`

Answer (score 34):

swift 3 date extension with timezone

```
extension Date {
    public func setTime(hour: Int, min: Int, sec: Int, timeZoneAbbrev: String = "UTC") -> Date? {
        let x: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        let cal = Calendar.current
        var components = cal.dateComponents(x, from: self)

        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timeZoneAbbrev)
        components.hour = hour
        components.minute = min
        components.second = sec

        return cal.date(from: components)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you must include `.timeZone` in the components

Answer (score 4):

```
//Increase the day & hours in Swift

let dateformat = DateFormatter()
let timeformat = DateFormatter()
        
dateformat.dateStyle = .medium
timeformat.timeStyle = .medium

//Increase Day

let currentdate = Date()

let currentdateshow = dateformat.string(from: currentdate)
textfield2.text = currentdateshow

let myCurrentdate = dateformat.date(from: dateTimeString)!
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: myCurrentdate) // Increase 1 Day

let tomorrowday = dateformat.string(from: tomorrow!)
text3.text = tomorrowday
text3.isEnabled = false
  
//increase Time  
    
let time = Date()

let currenttime = timeformat.string(from: time)
text4.text = currenttime
        
let mycurrenttime = timeformat.date(from: currenttime)!
let increasetime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 2, to: mycurrenttime) //increase 2 hrs.

let increasemytime = timeformat.string(from: increasetime!)
text5.text = increasemytime
```