# Setting time for tomorrow in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I need to get a Date object set for tomorrow at a certain time. I can figure out how to change the date to tomorrow but not how to set the time. Here is my function:

```
func getTomorrowAt(hour: Int, minutes: Int) -> Date {
   let calendar = Calendar.current
   var date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())

   // here I need to set the time to hour:minutes


   return date!
}
```

Comment: You can use `(NS)DateComponents` for that. For instance, you can set the date you want to `Date()` (now), and then add 1 day as you did on it.

Comment: How do I get DateComponenets to have today's date and a specific time then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073704/how-to-change-the-current-days-hours-and-minutes-swift-2

Comment: thanks. got it! Nice trick to first set the time and then add :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the hours and mins to this function:

```
func getTomorrowAt(hour: Int, minutes: Int) -> Date {
let today = Date()
let morrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)
return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minutes, second: 0, of: morrow)

}
```

[image]

Comment: Use DateComponents and not TimeInterval math if your dates really matter.    You should not assume there are 24*60*60 seconds in every day.  This code, for instance is off whenever a leap second is added to the current day.

Answer (score 1):

```
let greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let now = Date()
var components = greg.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: now)
components.hour = 10
components.minute = 35
components.second = 0

let date = greg.date(from: components)!
```