# Date from Calendar.dateComponents returning nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

I'm trying create a `Date` object with day, month and year, but the function of Calendar is returning `nil`.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: Date()).date! // <- nil
```

How I create a `Date` object only with day, month and year?

Comment: You don't. A `Date` is a point in time. The closest you can get is midnight (locale time or UTC time or some other specific timezone of your choosing).

Comment: if you don't care about time, Apple recommends that you set the time to noon. Daylight Saving Time may cause certain locations to have no midnight or two midnights in a day. As for how to set the time part of a date, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073704/how-to-change-the-current-days-hours-and-minutes-in-swift/36082867#36082867)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/227/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to strip off the time portion of a date (set it to midnight), then you can use `Calendar startOfDay`:

```
let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
```

This will give you midnight local time for the current date.

If you want midnight of the current date for a different timezone, create a new `Calendar` instance and set its `timeZone` as needed.

Comment: For time insensitive calendrical calculations it is better to use noon

Comment: @LeoDabus That should be a comment on the question, not this answer. The OP simply asked how to create a date with no time. We have no idea how it is to be used.

Comment: @rmaddy A date with "no time" should be using noon

Comment: That's what I needed.

Comment: A `Date` (As in a `Date` object) with no time does not exist. A `Date` object describes an instant in time. You can convert it to a string with just the date, or you can extract the time components from a `Date`, but a `Date` always has an associated time.

Comment: There are scenarios where a calendar program (or other time-management) software is trying to point to "a day" (and not a literal point-initime). The question might have been better with more context, rather than leaving us to speculate.

Answer (score 18):

As a supplement to rmaddy's answer, the reason *why* your code returns `nil`
is that you try to convert `DateComponents` to a `Date` without specifying a
`Calendar`.

If that conversion is done with a calendar method

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())
let date = calendar.date(from: components)
```

or if you add the calendar to the date components

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .calendar], from: Date()).date
```

then you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Adding `.calendar` to the original code is a really good insight. Good Info.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but in my REPL with Swift 5.2, I still get nil with your sample above... Any idea?

Comment: @barley Could be this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60504976/1187415

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, thanks for the reply and the answer above!!

Comment: @MartinR correct, I was working in the xCode debugger and the variable was showing as nil, however it actually had a value