# Swift date(byAdding:to:) returns nil for trivial calculation in REPL

Tags: swift, date, read-eval-print-loop

I expect this to return a `Date` object representing the time one hour from now:

```swift
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(hour: 1), to: Date())
```

However it returns `nil`. This seems like a rather straightforward use of the API so perhaps I have some fundamental misconception about how this API should work?

This *only* appears to affect the `swift` command line REPL included with Xcode (version 11.3.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.3).

Interestingly, wrapping the above code in a `print()` call forces it to print the correct result. So why is it showing `nil`?

```
Apple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Swift REPL, see

- [SR-11593 REPL incorrectly reports URL as nil](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11593)
- [SR-12172 Description of Date? expression is printed as nil even when non-nil](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12172)

It affects both optional and non-optional values of some Swift overlay types (such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `URL`). Example:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2>  
  3> let d1 = Date()
d1: Date = {}
  4> let d2: Date? = Date()
d2: Date? = nil
  5> let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
url: URL? = nil
```

As a workaround you can *print* the values:

```
  7> print(d1)
2020-03-03 10:17:00 +0000
  8> print(d2)
Optional(2020-03-03 10:17:07 +0000)
  9> print(url)
Optional(https://www.google.com)
```