# Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date()) is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get previous month using the following code in Swift

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())
```

But it is returning nil value. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try this in a REPL? Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459151/swift-datebyaddingto-returns-nil-for-trivial-calculation-in-repl.

Comment: nah, I can't replicate it – every single calendar returns the correct date: one month slow.