# Why is DateFormatter.date always returning nil?

Tags: swift, datetime

I'm attempting to convert a string to a `Date` object in Swift 4. I have the following code:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us_POSIX")
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
self.notificationTime = dateFormatter.date(from: notificationTimeString!)
```

Where `notificationTimeString` is `"2020-10-10T09:10:00"`

The `.date` call *always* returns nil. Further, from the debugger:

```
(lldb) e dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
(String) $R0 = "2020-10-10T14:14:06"
(lldb) e dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-10T14:14:06")
(Date?) $R2 = nil
```

Even, it seems, the output from itself isn't matching the format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `print(dateFormatter.date(from: ...)` also print “nil” or is it only the debugger output? Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/58855037/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/60459151/1187415.

Comment: omg. I didn't think about printing it: `Optional(2020-10-10 19:14:06 +0000)`

Comment: Besides the bug mentioned by Martin R, you should set your locale **before** setting the dateFormat. You should also make sure your date string is current timezone or UTC

Comment: That was it. It's showing in both lldb and in the locals window as nil. I had a different set of issues initially, but this has led to a day+ of head banging.